# searching for resource files in other modules when running tests

Tags: java, scala, testing, module

I have a project with 5 modules. When I try to run test for specific module, I get path does not exists error because tests are looking for resources in other modules.

this is the path I am trying to pass

```
src/test/resources/data/stg.csv
```

and this is my project structure

[image]

How do I make it so test look for resources in the module I need?

EDIT

I tried to run tests for the module `ucp...` was referencing `agg..` which in turn started searching for resources in the third module `actuall...`. Funily enough that one actually works(only one of the 5 that does) and paths are passed the same way in all of them.

CODE

```
  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    parameters = Parameters(TestUtils.args)

    loadTestTables(spark, parameters)
  }

  def loadTestTables(implicit spark: SparkSession, parameters: Parameters): Unit = {
    createTable(path, Table.schema, parameters.TABLE_STG_FAIR_DEBT)

  }

  def createTable(path: String, scheme: StructType, tableName: String, delimiter: String = "\t")(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    spark.read.schema(scheme)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", delimiter)
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .load(path)
      .createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
  }
```

Comment: **How** are you trying to access that resource?

Comment: @ern By passing the path to it to a method that will read it? What do you mean by how?

Comment: If you're reading from code, then it's almost certainly incorrect to use `src/...` as path, because the objective is to make the `data/...` part be available under the classpath root. How you read the file matters because paths may need to vary based on whether you're using file IO, classpath resource APIs, etc.

Comment: From which package are you trying to access it? `ucp-fair-usage/src/test/scala`?

Comment: @erip yes from `ucp-fair-usage` instead it goes looking inside `agg-fair-usage`

Comment: Can you show your code? It's hard to guess why without your attempt.

Comment: @erip updated. Also added a note about how one of the modules works. The code is the same for all 5 of them.

Comment: I don't see the code where you try to actually access the resource.

Comment: @erip have you tried looking? At this `.load(path)` row for example?

Comment: @Evgenii You should not patronize people from whom you're asking help. That is not how a specific resource is accessed -- that's how an arbitrary resource is accessed. If you pass the wrong path, it clearly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in working directory.

Edit Configuration -> working directory -> choose path to module